# SQL Server: the reason for process blocking in the past

Tags: sql-server, blocked

We are using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition.

Normally we get hardly any blocked processes, but last weekend we experienced very unusual situation. Within 2 hours we got more "blocked process" alerts than we did in the last year together. There were a few hundred alerts within this time. Then suddenly without any interference from anyone everything went back to norm and we didn't get any blocked processes ever since. I want to prevent this situation from occurring again.

I am well aware how to find what can be causing blocking at present, but I have very little idea how to find what caused the block in the past, which is currently resolved.

I checked error logs in SQL Server Management Studio, but there is nothing there under the date when blocking occurred. There is also nothing unusual in the Windows event viewer. Where else should I check?

Could you please help?

Comment: You can check if anyone ran an unusual report or application at this time and try running again. IIt really sound like a very demanding report was doing it. Also, check if any other non related applications were experiencing problems at the same moment: it could be a network problem

Comment: Obviously, activate the Activity monitor when you rerun the reports or queries you're suspicious of.

Comment: @JoBedard Thank you for your answer. How do I check what reports were run at that time? Asking around is impossible as there are simply too many users.

Comment: look for a database called ReportServer on your server and a view called ExecutionLOG, it keeps 60 days of log by default. Google the term  ExecutionLOG as they are variants depending on your server version. For example https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159110%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @JoBedard Thank you Jo. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, I'm not too sure you will actually find the cause of the previously blocking processes if you did not actively setup tracing i.e. have your blocked process threshold set and configured with an alert to provide said trace information. The situation you described is interesting and definitely worth monitoring.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181150.aspx) is an article on blocked process threshold configuration in SQL Server and a link through to Alerts configuration.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the link. We have something very similar already set up. Normally we don't get any blocking at all. This is why this situation surprised me so much.

Comment: @QWE: were you able to pinpoint the source of the problem with DMV's such as `sys.dm_tran_locks` , `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` , `sys.sysprocesses` ? Also, I'm just guessing now but if you are possibly referring to an SSRS report, in the comment section of your original post, you could possibly query the various ExecutionLog views in the ReportServer database.